# How to see the Video Card Temperature (Nvidia, ATI, Intel...)

Tags: video, temperature

Is there a command (Via terminal) to see the temperature of any video card.

Already Tried `sensors` with the `sensors-detect` applied. Does not detect for example, Nvidia and ATI video card temperatures.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, there is a command.

**Detecting sensors**

First of all, you have to search for sensors:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect
```

Since lucid lynx, you have to type:

```
sudo service module-init-tools start
```

If you're running another Ubuntu version type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/module-init-tools start
```

To save the detection results.

**Displaying sensor data**

Now, to show the temperatures, type:

```
sensors
```

Now you should see something like that:

[image: My sensors result]

I don't have many sensors, btw :)

**Displaying temperature of NVIDIA GPU**

If you are using a NVIDIA GPU type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvclock
```

After installing it, type `nvclock -T` to display the temperature.

You can also type `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp`.

I hope this helped you,

Comment: Thank you Daniel but sensors does not detect the video temp for cases like ati and nvidia. i should have put it in the question but forgot. +1 for complete example.

Comment: @CYREX After some researches I found out that it also shows GPU temp if you install libsensors3 BEFORE detecting sensors. Try: `sudo apt-get install libsensors3` and then follow my steps again.

Comment: Nope no luck either. Only shows the CPU temp.

Comment: Some programs made by nvidia/ati display the GPU temp.

Comment: @CYREX I added instructions to display the temperature of a nvidia gpu, look at my edited answer.

Comment: None of these work for me; however, @drgrog suggestion does.

Comment: If you use an **ATI GPU** (Radeon...) proprietary driver (fglrx), run `sudo aticonfig --initial` once then `aticonfig --odgt --odgc` to display GPU temperature and load.

Comment: For AMD GPU, in 16.04: `apt install lm-sensors` followed by `sensors-detect`

Comment: Neither `sensors-detect` nor `sensors` worked on my stock 16.04. I had to first install the `lm-sensors` package (`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`). I have an NVIDIA card. `nvidia-settings` worked, but I had the NVIDIA 340.X drivers already installed. `Psensor` GUI (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/psensor/1.1.3-2ubuntu5) works very well.

Comment: Kubuntu 21.10 does not know a package "nvclock"

Answer (score 114):

An alternative for nvidia cards is to use nvidia-smi: the "NVIDIA System Management Interface program".

```
user@box:~$ nvidia-smi -q -d temperature
GPU 0:
            Product Name            : GeForce 210
            PCI ID                  : a6510de
            Temperature             : 39 C
```

Or to output just the numeric value in Celsius:

```
user@box:~$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader
39
```

Comment: optirun nvidia-smi -q -d temperature

Comment: In case anyone missed it, `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp` is another method.

Comment: How do you handle when all GPU cores are at 100% and your `nvidia-smi` command hangs until a core is freed?  Thus defeating the purpose of 'alarm on meltdown'?  Am I reduced to an aftermarket temperature sensor?  The 2080Ti GPU apparently won't read its own temperature on 100% usage, and doesn't know to turn on its own fan, nor halt because of >135C literal melting temperatures.  Looks like it's time for unpacking their Propitiatory C binaries and do it like they do on blizzard gamedevs.  Well played nvidia, angry noises.

Comment: `Memory Current Temp: N/A` -> what to do?

Answer (score 18):

The already mentioned command for nvidia (on my OpenElec installation):

```
nvidia-smi
```

also gave additional information:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 3.295.71   Driver Version: 295.71         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Nb.  Name                     | Bus Id        Disp.  | Volatile ECC SB / DB |
| Fan   Temp   Power Usage /Cap | Memory Usage         | GPU Util. Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0.  GeForce GT 520            | 0000:01:00.0  N/A    |       N/A        N/A |
|  N/A   52 C  N/A   N/A /  N/A |  17%  169MB / 1023MB |  N/A      Default    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU  PID     Process name                                       Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  0.           Not Supported                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to watch the temperature in your terminal for monitoring, you can use `watch` with the commands that were given in the other answers (e.g. @drgrog's). For instance, to refresh the temperature every 5 seconds:

```
watch -n 5 nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader
```

Answer (score 4):

For nvidia there is an `nvidia-settings` package, which includes a gui to see the temperature.  I don't recall if there is a text-mode tool in there.

Some Intel graphics adapters report their temperature through acpi and you can read it through the `sensors` command from the package of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently found a cool extension for Gnome 3. So if you are using it - you can install this and see the temperature in the tray:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/541/nvidia-gpu-temperature-indicator/

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a quick simple way to see the GPU and CPU temps on my computer. I also wanted to see the NVidia temp in fahrenheit. Assuming you already have the `nvidia-smi` and `sensors` utilities installed, configured and working already (see above for how), you can use the following script to display everything together:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo ""

echo "GPU Current Temp"
echo "Core 0:       +$(( $((`nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader` * 9/5)) + 32))°F"
# nvidia-smi --query --display=TEMPERATURE | grep "GPU Current Temp" --color=none | sed 's/        //g'

echo ""

echo "CPU Current Temp"
sensors coretemp-isa-0000 -f | sed 's/(high.*//g' | tail -n +4 | sed 's/\.[0-9]//g'
```

NOTE: you may need to change `coretemp-isa-0000` to the identifier if your computer uses a different architecture than mine.

The output will look something like:

```
GPU Current Temp
Core 0:       +120°F

CPU Current Temp
Core 0:       +167°F  
Core 1:       +176°F  
Core 2:       +156°F  
Core 3:       +152°F  
Core 4:       +147°F  
Core 5:       +143°F
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicator also includes GPU temp (as well as CPU and HDD temps.)

https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors

Answer (score 0):

After installing nvclock, just running:

nvidia-settings

On a terminal worked well on GeForce 210 card on top of Ubuntu 14lts. 
You get a very nice GUI and can check the celsius temperature at GPU 0 > Thermal Settings.

Answer (score 0):

## GPU Temperature with Conky

Conky is a light weight (on resources, not features) system monitor popular in Linux. You can use it to constantly display GPU temperature along with other system elements you like to follow.

Most laptops with nVidia GPUs also include an Intel Integrated GPU (iGPU) for use when on battery power.

My Conky display changes depending on whether Intel or nVidia is selected.

Below are GIFs for nVidia and Intel before and running `glxgears` to tax the GPU. I'll try to find a more demanding graphics test than `glxgears` in the future.

### Display for Laptop with NVIDIA active

Here's what my Conky looks like when `prime-select nvidia` is active:

[image: gpu temp nvidia]

Initially there is low load on nVidia GPU and it's running at 746 MHz and is 55 degrees Celsius. After running `glxgears` GPU speed spikes to max speed of 1037 MHz and temperature climbs to 58 degrees Celsius.

### Display for Laptop with Intel Integrated GPU active

Here's what my Conky looks like when `prime-select intel` is active:

[image: intel GPU]

Initially there is low load on Intel Integrated GPU (iGPU) and temperature (of CPU) is 49 degrees Celsius. After running `glxgears` CPU temperature climbs to 73 degrees Celsius!

### Conky code

Here is the relevant conky code for above:

```
#------------+
# Temperature|
#------------+
#${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone7/temp | cut -c1-2}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
# Next line is for kernel >= 4.13.0-36-generic
${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 1 temp 1}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
# Next line is for temperature with Kerenel 4.4
#${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
${color green}$running_processes ${color1}running of ${color green}$processes ${color1}loaded processes.
${color1}Load Average 1-5-15 minutes: ${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $1}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $2}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $3}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4}
#------------+
# Intel iGPU |
#------------+
${color orange}${hr 1}${if_match "intel" == "${execpi 99999 prime-select query}"}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU @${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_cur_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color}${goto 13}Min. Freq:${goto 120}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_min_freq_mhz)} MHz${color}${goto 210}Max. Freq:${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_max_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color orange}${hr 1}${else}
#------------+
# Nvidia GPU |
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)}°C
${color1}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color1}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${color orange}${hr 1}${endif}
```

Comment: I couldn't load this config file into `$HOME/.conkyrc`. I think this might be outdated

Comment: @morhook It may have to be updated for the latest version of conky but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.04 if it helps. Installed package conky-all version 1.11.6-2

Answer (score 0):

For anybody in the year 2024 an above. There are 2 excellent tools in Gnome, for this.

**Vitals** - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

This one has an option to show the Video card Temperature and other factors as well. It is the one I use. Here is a screenshot:

**Freon** - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/

This is another one that also offers similar features.

[image]

[image]

For Console cases, you could use nvidia-smi for Nvidia cards for example like this

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=timestamp,name,pci.bus_id,driver_version,pstate,pcie.link.gen.max,pcie.link.gen.current,temperature.gpu,utilization.gpu,utilization.memory,memory.total,memory.free,memory.used,power.draw,clocks.sm,clocks.mem,clocks.gr --format=csv -l 1
```

Which would return a very thorough and detailed analysis of the Nvidia card

[image]

```
2024/02/25 09:45:57.835, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P5, 4, 2, 45, 19 %, 19 %, 24564 MiB, 23129 MiB, 1047 MiB, 27.32 W, 405 MHz, 810 MHz, 405 MHz
2024/02/25 09:45:58.839, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P5, 4, 2, 45, 21 %, 21 %, 24564 MiB, 23130 MiB, 1046 MiB, 27.88 W, 405 MHz, 810 MHz, 405 MHz
2024/02/25 09:45:59.842, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P0, 4, 4, 45, 95 %, 81 %, 24564 MiB, 23130 MiB, 1046 MiB, 32.90 W, 2580 MHz, 10501 MHz, 2580 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:00.845, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P0, 4, 4, 45, 1 %, 2 %, 24564 MiB, 23142 MiB, 1034 MiB, 62.90 W, 2580 MHz, 10501 MHz, 2580 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:01.847, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P3, 4, 4, 45, 2 %, 4 %, 24564 MiB, 23146 MiB, 1030 MiB, 57.20 W, 600 MHz, 5001 MHz, 600 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:02.850, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P3, 4, 4, 44, 4 %, 4 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 37.72 W, 420 MHz, 5001 MHz, 420 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:03.853, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P3, 4, 4, 44, 5 %, 4 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 37.15 W, 345 MHz, 5001 MHz, 345 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:04.855, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P3, 4, 4, 44, 5 %, 4 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 36.64 W, 285 MHz, 5001 MHz, 285 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:05.858, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P5, 4, 2, 44, 17 %, 18 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 34.01 W, 330 MHz, 810 MHz, 330 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:06.861, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P5, 4, 2, 44, 20 %, 20 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 26.49 W, 390 MHz, 810 MHz, 390 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:07.865, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P5, 4, 2, 43, 20 %, 20 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 26.79 W, 390 MHz, 810 MHz, 390 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:08.870, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P8, 4, 1, 43, 32 %, 32 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 26.56 W, 540 MHz, 405 MHz, 540 MHz
2024/02/25 09:46:09.876, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, 00000000:01:00.0, 550.40.07, P5, 4, 2, 43, 19 %, 20 %, 24564 MiB, 23196 MiB, 980 MiB, 26.64 W, 705 MHz, 810 MHz, 705 MHz
```

For KDE, I need to wait for Plasma 6 to test which ones will work properly at the UI level.