# How can I see the temperature of a video card?

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see the Video Card Temperature (Nvidia, Ati, Intel…)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34449/how-to-see-the-video-card-temperature-nvidia-ati-intel)

I have one laptop that presents/displays problems to me by heating, I need to know like seeing the temperature of my laptop and preventing an overheat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using lm-sensors utility [ http://www.lm-sensors.org ]. Install it and run the command sensors.

One more thing is that you can use cooling fan pads for cooling down your laptop. They are cheap (starting from $15) work well.