# Ubuntu 12.04 and KDE, graphical temperature monitor for GPU

Tags: 12.04, kde, gpu, temperature, sensors

I have ubuntu 12.04 and KDE. I already installed "lm-sensors", "hardware sensors indicator" and "Psensors" but none works well for me. 
I also know a couple of commands to find gpu temperature on terminal but I don't need that, I need a graphical application that works with kde to use.

Do you know something that helps me?

My card is MSI R6870 Hawk (from ATI original HD6870) and I have **fglrx drivers**

Thanks

Comment: I've not used KDE recently but they have loads of [Plasmoids](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Plasma/Plasmoids), some do system monitoring. Have you tried any?

Comment: yes, I tried all plasmoids with sys monitor but no gpu temperature

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the type of video card please? Also, see [this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/34449/12864) for ideas. It may not be possible depending on what card it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SuperKaramba ?**

http://netdragon.sourceforge.net/ssuperkaramba.html

> What is SuperKaramba?
>
> SuperKaramba is, in simple terms, a tool that allows you to easily
>   create interactive eye-candy on your KDE desktop.

**KDE Plasma support**

Package: plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba

> Description: SuperKaramba theme support for the Plasma Workspaces 
>   This package provides SuperKaramba scriptengine for Plasma. It brings 
>   support for the SuperKaramba interactive desktop applets, called
>   "themes", to  the Plasma desktop. This package is part of the KDE
>   SC utilities module.

**KDE-Look**

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=91918

> Description: This widget will display current ATI screen card fan
>   speed and temperature.  It will also allow the modification of the fan
>   speed in 5% increments.

**At here**

Downloading the widget - unpacking it - starting the Karamba: Alt+F2 karamba.
Adding the local theme...

Seems to work at here.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks, I have installed superkaramba and then the widget but it requires libkrosspython0 and I don`t know how to install it.

Comment: howerver I found other good widgets thanks you so much.

Comment: @Frank If you found other widgets, which is not from this answer, I suggest you to add an answer from yourself. this way we can help new visitors with the same problem. Thanks