# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS random hard shutdown with Nvidia RTX 2080

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, shutdown, crash

I've got a brand new laptop with a Nvidia RTX 2080 and I am facing hard shutdowns randomly. I already reinstalled the driver several times (now via ppa as mentioned here: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Additionally, I checked the temperature of the CPU (I9 9900K) with sensors and the GPU temp with nvidia-smi -q -d temperature as mentioned here: [How to see the Video Card Temperature (Nvidia, ATI, Intel...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34449/how-to-see-the-video-card-temperature-nvidia-ati-intel)

I also checked if nouveau is enabled as mentioned here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ixzz4rQODN0jy (scroll down to the section about nouveau)

Secure boot is disabled. I have a M.2 card with win10 and a ssd hard drive with ubuntu on it. The issue seems to appear when I restart out of windows and then boot ubuntu (by pressing f7 to get into boot menu etc...). It also happens once on a fresh startup.

So when the random hard shutdown out of ubuntu happens, the computer will then turn on again by itself and I can press f7 in order to boot ubuntu. I am not really sure but this never happens if I start ubuntu and then restart ubuntu again. I already checked the logs /var/log/syslog kern.log etc. but nothing there. I am not a linux pro, so I don't know where I can find information about such "crashes". Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: This issue didn't happen in Windows 10.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Brand new desktop, with GeForce 2080. It came with nouveau + 19.04. After installation of the driver via ppa, the reboots started. I tried three of the suggested drivers (410, 410, 430), but got the same problem. I then installed from scratch a 18.04 and tried a couple of the suggested drivers via pps and the .run of the 418 downloaded from nvidia website, but still the random reboots persisted. Nothing in the syslog. Graphic card temperature normal.
A guy in a forum (sorry, I don't remember where) said it solved theproblem installing the 390 version, but it

Comment: Do you Win10 on a second disk too? This problem only appears, when windows was booted before ubuntu